# Error and effect - Dumas method

Tags: experimental-chemistry

The Dumas method is the easiest approach to measure the molarity of Gases. However, this method assumes that all the vapor (i.e. from a vessel) is condensed in, for example, an ice bath.

What are the errors from the Dumas method? I believe that Henri-Victor Regnault stated this error but I cannot find any good explanation.